# When should we use capitalization when writing research papers?

Tags: capitalization

I am wondering how many cases we should notice when using capitalization (except the word standing at the beginning of the sentences, place name) in an academic paper.

For example:

"Days of Payable Outstanding" in " **We use Days of Payable Outstanding as....**" or should we use " **We use days of payable outstanding as....** "

"**The President of the US**" or "**The president of the US**"

Comment: What do the other research papers you've read do?

Comment: @DM_with_secrets they used these words quite flexible while I want something consistently

Comment: In that case, just be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the same capitalization rules in academic writing as you would normally follow when writing in English.

From [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/)

1. Capitalize the first word of a sentence
2. Capitalize names and other proper nouns
3. Don’t capitalize after a colon (usually)
4. Capitalize the first word of a quote (sometimes)
5. Capitalize days, months, and holidays, but not seasons
6. Capitalize most words in titles
7. Capitalize cities, countries, nationalities, and languages
8. Capitalize time periods and events (sometimes)

Grammarly left out one rule: Capitalize titles for (certain) political offices.  The president of your school wouldn't be capitalized, but the President of the United States of America should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

If the paper s to be published in a journal or similar academic publication, there is probably a specified style guide to be followed. If there is, follow it strictly. If not, follow the same rules as othe papers in the same field recently published. If there is a specific style guide normally used in the relevant field, follow it. This applies to all style issues and particularly to citation formats, not just to capitalization.

The principles given in the answer by JRF are good general guidelines, but if the specific style rules applicable in the particular field differ, follow the more specific rules.

When a particular technical term is being introduced, defined, and used, some fields will capitalize that term, others may use italics on first mention or other ways or marking the term.